# Let $*$ be the operation $a*b = ab^2$ over the integers. Is this a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, associativity

I'm trying to prove associativity and I think this operation fails.

This is what I have: 
$$\begin{align}
(a*b)*c &= a*(b*c)\\
(ab^2)*c &= a*(bc^2)\\
(ab^2)(c^2) &= (a)(bc^2)^2\\
ab^2c^2 &\neq ab^2c^4
\end{align}$$

Comment: All you still need is examples of integers $a$, $b$ and $c$ so that the final line holds.

Comment: Alternatively, $1$ would have to be the identity for this operation. Then $2$ can't have an inverse because $2*b=2b^2$ is even, and can't ever be 1.

Comment: What you have in your post is what might be called "scratch work" for the final answer. All that you need to show or even should show in almost all cases (notable exceptions: an expository article, test, or textbook) is the example that proves your point. You absolutely should do scratch work and write a "rough draft" of the solution, which can include your train of thought. Your "final draft," however, should only prove what needs to be shown as clearly and concisely as possible. In this way, a math proof is just like an essay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. Well done!

Let $a=b=1, c=2$. That would complete things.

It would be a better proof, though, in my opinion, if you put sentences or at least punctuation marks between the equations. (This is just better form.)

Comment: I am never sure about punctuation between equations. I was once told (by someone I respect greatly, and who cares deeply about these things!) that putting implies arrows ($\Rightarrow$) with each equation/line looks amateurish. There is also the debate as to whether one should end such a sequence of equations with a full stop (I feel that it is ambiguous here as the colon ends the sentence, while "This is what I have," would require a full stop in the last line...).

Comment: Perfect! I wasn't sure if it was necessary but I should use a counterexample to solidify the proof. I usually do include things like that to strengthen my argument but wasn't sure if it was unnecessary information. In response to @user1729, In this case as a conclusion I wrote out "Shown above, $(m*n)*o \neq m*(n*o)$." and used punctuation there, but didn't when I was showing the centered work I posted here.

Comment: An introductory description and a conclusive statement at the end would be nice in a formal proof, but the actual content seems perfectly fine as is.